# addressing cell arrays of structures

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have following cell array:

```
res{1}.nft.x=1;
res{2}.nft.x=2;
res{3}.nft.x=3;
```

How can I easily get an array of `nft.x` values, i.e., `[1 2 3]` in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: If possible, you want an array of structures, not a cell array of structures.  This way, MATLAB knows that each element of the array has the same fields.  That is, `res(1).nft.x=1;`, etc.  Then [res.nft] does something sensible.

Comment: @Peter well then again `[res.nft].x` doesn't work, so what is the advantage?

Comment: `t=[res.nft]; myx=[t.x];`  The temporary is only because MATLAB *still* doesn't support dereferencing an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `cellfun`

```
>> cellfun( @(x) x.nft.x, res )
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [comma-separated lists](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?s_tid=doc_12b) (a very powerful feature in MATLAB):

```
v = [res{:}];
v = [v.nft];
v = [v.x];
```

Of course, this only works if all structures have the identical fields. If not, you'll have to resort to a loop or something similar, for instance:

```
cellfun(@(x)x.nft.x, res)
```

the latter may seem a bit more elegant, but it's definitely much slower for a larger data set.

#### Clarification

`res{:}` creates a comma separated list of structs, and `[res{:}]` concatenates them into an array. Accessing a field of an array of structs again results in a comma separated list, hence the additional concatenation, field access and yet another concatenation.

Comment: @hovo works for me. "doesn't work" is not very informative... what is the error you're getting?

Comment: `Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator.` pointing at the first dot.

Comment: @hovo are you positive that you run the same example as in the question?

Comment: actually I just running your code in octave and it does work. So this might be a MATLAB version difference.

Comment: Hmm, field access of a temporary struct (created by `horzcat` at least) no longer works in R2013b.

Comment: @hovo Interesting. I've split the answer into three statements. This should guarantee that it'd work.